# How to write type script in react action

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This is my action file, It's .js file

```
export const fetchData = () => (dispatch, getState, apolloClient) => {
  dispatch({ type: FETCH_DATA });

  apolloClient
    .query({
      query: TEST_GQL,
      variables: {
        limit: 100,
      },
    })
    .then((res) => {
      const data = res.data;

      if (data.error) {
        return dispatch({
          type: ERROR_FETCHING_DATA,
          payload: data.error,
        });
      }

      return dispatch({
        type: FETCHED_DATA,
        payload: data.data,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => dispatch({
      type: ERROR_FETCHING_DATA,
      payload: err,
    }));
};
```

How to convert this file on typescript

Comment: Could you share `TEST_GQL`, `ERROR_FETCHING_DATA`,`ERROR_FETCHING_DATA`,`FETCHED_DATA`, `ERROR_FETCHING_DATA` types plus `state` type??

Answer (score 0):

Based on your information in the code, you can transform your code to :

```
import { ApolloClient } from "@apollo/client";
import { Dispatch } from "redux";

export type State = {}; // it should be your state which fetchData gives

//these are strings which you use them on fetchData
const TEST_GQL = "TEST_GQL"; 
const FETCH_DATA = "FETCH_DATA";
const ERROR_FETCHING_DATA = "ERROR_FETCHING_DATA";
const FETCHED_DATA = "FETCHED_DATA";

export const fetchData = () => (
  dispatch: Dispatch,
  getState: () => State,
  apolloClient: ApolloClient<any>
) => {
  dispatch({ type: FETCH_DATA });

  apolloClient
    .query({
      query: TEST_GQL,
      variables: {
        limit: 100
      }
    })
    .then((res) => {
      const data = res.data;

      if (data.error) {
        return dispatch({
          type: ERROR_FETCHING_DATA,
          payload: data.error
        });
      }

      return dispatch({
        type: FETCHED_DATA,
        payload: data.data
      });
    })
    .catch((err) =>
      dispatch({
        type: ERROR_FETCHING_DATA,
        payload: err
      })
    );
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what my answer.

but i hope, this code will be help you!

```html
import { Dispatch } from "redux";

export const fetchData = () => (dispatch : Dispatch, getState : any /* ex) (val)=>void */, apolloClient : any /* must be apolloclient class type!*/ ) => {
    let FETCH_DATA : string = "";
    let TEST_GQL : string = "";
    let ERROR_FETCHING_DATA : string = "";
    let FETCHED_DATA : string = "";
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_DATA });
  
    apolloClient
      .query({
        query: TEST_GQL,
        variables: {
          limit: 100,
        },
      })
      .then((res : { data : any } /* must be apolloclient response type */) => {
        const data = res.data;
  
        if (data.error) {
          return dispatch({
            type: ERROR_FETCHING_DATA,
            payload: data.error,
          });
        }
  
        return dispatch({
          type: FETCHED_DATA,
          payload: data.data,
        });
      })
      .catch((err : any) => dispatch({
        type: ERROR_FETCHING_DATA,
        payload: err,
      }));
  };
```